# Не могу решить задачу на Pуthоn

Tags: python

Напишите программу для выделения топота и бряцания из шума.
Топотом будем считать числа с нулем в конце, бряцанием – кратные 11, шумом – все остальные.

Формат ввода:

Вводится число, ввод которого служит признаком остановки считывания строк. Затем вводятся строки чисел, записанных через точку с запятой и пробел. Количество чисел в строках одинаково.

Формат вывода:

Из каждого столбца нужно выбрать числа – топот и бряцание – и, если кроме них был еще шум, то вывести эти числа для каждого столбца без повторений в порядке возрастания. Если же в каком-либо столбце не было шума или не было искомых чисел, то вывести HIKE CONTINUES, завершить поиск и вывести числа только из предыдущих столбцов.

Мой код:

```
StopKey = int(input())
AllNumbers = list()
CountCollection = list()
CountCollection2 = list()

while True:
    Numbers = str(input())
    if Numbers == str(StopKey):
        break
    Numbers = Numbers.split("; ")
    AllNumbers.append(Numbers)

for elem in range(len(AllNumbers[0])):
    for el in range(len(AllNumbers)):
        Count = AllNumbers[el][elem]
        if (Count[-1] == "0") or (int(Count) % 11 == 0):
            CountCollection.append(int(Count))

    if (len(CountCollection) >= 1) or (len(CountCollection) < len(AllNumbers)):
        CountCollection.sort()
        for i in CountCollection:
            i = str(i)
            CountCollection2.append(i)
        print(" ".join(CountCollection2))
        CountCollection2 = list()
        CountCollection = list()
    else:
        print("HIKE CONTINUES")
```

Ввел:

```
100
198; 61; 46; 121
163; 285; 211; 29
90; 3; 4; 250
247; 102; 165; 99
211; 85; 100; 95
100
```

Должно было вывести:

```
HIKE CONTINUES
90 198
```

У меня вывело:

```
90 198

100 165
99 121 250
```

Решите задачу пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вот так сделал все (если я правильно понял задачу):

```
stopKey = input()

data = []

while True:
    line = input()
    if line == stopKey:
        break
    data.append(list(map(int, line.split("; "))))

for column_index in range(len(data[0])):
    stomping = set(row[column_index] for row in data if row[column_index] % 10 == 0)
    rattling = set(row[column_index] for row in data if row[column_index] % 11 == 0)
    noise = set(row[column_index] for row in data) - (stomping | rattling)

    if len(stomping) == 0 or len(rattling) == 0 or len(noise) == 0:
        print("HIKE CONTINUES")
        break
    else:
        print(*sorted(list(stomping)), *sorted(list(rattling)))
```

Answer (score 0):

видел такую задачу недавно
вроде так решается

```
a = int(input())
b = input()
kol = list()
ans = list()
ans1 = list()
ind = 0
bil = ''
while b != str(a):
    kol.append(b.split("; "))
    b = input()
for i in range(len(kol[0])):
    for j in range(len(kol)):
        if int(kol[j][i]) % 10 == 0 or int(kol[j][i]) % 11 == 0 and kol[j][i] not in ans:
            ans1.append(int(kol[j][i]))
    ans.append(ans1)
    ans1 = list()
for i in range(len(ans)):
    if ans[i] == list():
        ind = i
        print("HIKE CONTINUES")
        break
    ind = i + 1
for i in range(ind):
    ans[i] = sorted(ans[i])
    for j in range(len(ans[i])):
        if str(ans[i][j]) not in bil:
            print(ans[i][j], end=" ")
            bil = ''.join(str(ans[i][j]))
    print()
```